# Use of temporary table variable inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle-11g

I am new to oracle, I was trying to create a procedure which consist of temporary table inside. I have tried this code below and getting an error in the declaration of temporary variable.

```
 DECLARE @TEMPDATA TABLE (TOTALQUANT numeric(18, 0));
    create or replace PROCEDURE ESTIMATION(FROMDATE IN DATE,TODATE IN DATE,USERID IN NUMBER)
    IS 
    BEGIN
    SELECT 
      SUM(z.QUANTITY)
    FROM x
    INNER JOIN y
    ON x.SURVEYID = y.SURVEYID
    INNER JOIN z
    ON z.SURVEYCRAFTID = y.SURVEYCRAFTID
     WHERE SURVEYDATE BETWEEN FROMDATE AND TODATE
    GROUP BY x.LCID,
      x.PERIODID,
      y.CRAFTID,
      y.GEARID;
     END ESTIMATION;
```

I am getting a syntax error of 'Partially recognised rule'.

Comment: If you are really using Oracle rather than SQL Server, you wouldn't prefix variable names with `@`, you wouldn't have a `declare` there, there is no such thing as a table variable, and you can't have a procedure that just does a `SELECT` without either selecting data into a scalar variable (or variables) or into a collection or opening a cursor that can be used or returned to the caller.  Since you're not manipulating data, it would also not make sense to create a procedure rather than a function.  Possibly, you want a function that returns a `sys_refcursor` but that's a wild guess.

Comment: @Justin Cave am from sql server side. thats why . Any way @ symbol works when we declare it outside the procedure

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "@ symbol works".  An Oracle nonquoted identifier cannot begin with or contain an @ sign (well a database link name can contain but not begin with an @ though I can't imagine why you'd want to do so) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm